# Why does Django perform UPDATE before INSERT when PK is None?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-database

I've got a model with a UUID primary key:

```
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key = True,
        default = uuid.uuid4,
        editable = False,
        null = False,
        blank = False,
        help_text = 'The unique identifier of the Node.'
    )
```

The issue I'm trying to solve is that Django *always* seems to try an Update before an Insert.

[The Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert) seem to be explicit on what the behavior should be: If `pk` is `None` then it will try an `INSERT` first, otherwise an `UPDATE`.

When I create a ModelInstance, it autopopulates `id` with a UUID, so it's not none. Is there a way I can make it not do this?

Regardless, even if I set `id` and `pk` to `None` on create, it *still* does an `UPDATE` first:

```
my_totally_new_node = Node(data = data, id = None, pk = None)
my_totally_new_node.id
> None
my_totally_new_node.pk
> None
reset_queries()

my_totally_new_node.save()

connection.queries
> [{'sql': 'UPDATE "connection_p...::uuid", 'time': '0.002'}, {'sql': 'INSERT INTO "connect...::bytea)", 'time': '0.001'}]
```

To summarize:

1. Is there a way I can cause default behavior for the ID field to be *not* to populate on create, but to still populate on Save?
2. Any ideas why Django isn't following the documented behavior when `pk` is `None` and is still trying an `INSERT` first?

I'm aware of the `save(force_insert=True)` workaround but I'm looking for a better way, partly because `create` doesn't support this workaround.

Comment: It is being automatically filled in because you have: `default = uuid.uuid4`.  To not have it do that remove the `default`. Then you will need some sort of mechanism on the server side to generate the `UUID`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for your answer. Just to clarify, by server side you mean on the database server?

Comment: Yes. Postgres has a [UUID](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/uuid-ossp.html) extension. I have not done it, but I could see using that to set a default on the table column in Postgres.